# Github not running PHP

Tags: php, github

ve been trying to make a server side site recently on Github but the php code will not run, I have put in a .htaccess but it still wont work, I was wondering if I need to put some library into it to interpret it but other peoples php codes seem to be working without anything like that. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about the GitHub Pages?

Comment: You can’t run server-side code with GitHub Pages. Only thing it does is return the contents of your repo as is, through a webserver.

Comment: Then how do other people do it? Im confused

Comment: Other people _don't_ do it, assuming you mean "run PHP code on GitHub Pages". Many other web hosts do support PHP.

Answer (score 2):

From https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/:

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

Comment: Do you know any websites that you can create on that do then?

Comment: There are zillions of web hosters which support PHP. You will have to find one which also supports git. Then you can pull your content from GitHub and publish on your own (hosted) server.

Comment: The problem is when I try find a website hoster all it comes up with are wix and that sort ads, I will try find one :P

Comment: If you have Linux knowledge, you could setup a LAMP on a virtual root server and do everything yourself without any ads.

Comment: @AdrianW - recommendation-style questions (e.g. asking for hosting companies) are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I know that. OP's original question was not to ask for hosting companies, but why PHP code is not executed on GitHub pages. The discussion on what OP could do instead took place in the comments. And yes, I agree, it is even off topic there. But may be it helps OP.